# React-native FlatList items not get to right height

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have items in diffrent heights (250 or 150) inside a FlatList, 
When iterate each item and append the state of the dataSrouce for the FlatList everything renders alright, but if I want to avoid the "appending" affect and set the dataSrouce to all of the items at once, it seem FlatList have a wierd bug where items are not getting their right height (There is a blank space on the botton where the item had suppose to fill it).

Tried put "*flexGrow:1*" on the FlatList, tried the "*initialNumToRender*" property,
Tried to fix height of the each Item in the view.

Container of the FlatList is "flex:1".

[image]

My FlatList:

```
  render() {
const _this = this;
const { loading } = this.state;
return (
  <Components.ViewContainer>
    {this.printTopHeader()}
    {loading ? (
      <ActivityIndicator size={25} />
    ) : (
      <FlatList
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        removeClippedSubviews={true} //tried with and without
        data={this.state.posts}
        extraData={this.state.posts} //tried with and without
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <HomeCard
            post={item}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
      />
    )}
  </Components.ViewContainer>
);
```

}

Components.ViewContainer:

```
const ViewContainer = styled.View`
flex:1;
`;
```

HomeCard:

```
  render() {
    const { theme, showActions } = this.props;
    const {
      imageUrl,
      user,
      title,
      selectedPlace,
      textColor,
      backgroundColor
    } = this.props.post;

    return (
      <Components.ContainerView>
...
 </Components.ContainerView>
    );
}
export default withTheme(HomeCard); // styled-components implementation
```

Comment: You need to add the code to demostrate this behaviour. Try adding the snippet to your question and generate an example [here](https://snack.expo.io)

Comment: Please your `FlatList` code.

Comment: @anhtu Added code snippet.

Comment: @PritishVaidya I didn't manage to repreduce the error there

Comment: Did you try explicit height for row?

Comment: "Tried to fix height of the each Item in the view.". Okie you did. 
Please post the `return` of the `HomeCard`. @ItayElkouby

Comment: @ItayElkouby I am in the same problem. Can you able to find any solution for this issue ??. I also need Dynamic Height based on Row Item height in FlatList.

Comment: @PankajNegi It was a matter of wrong styling, make sure you put `flex:1` properly on child components.

Comment: @ItayElkouby I have given position 'absolute' to child container which is causing the above error. thanks for your reply. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue were caused by a matter of wrong styling applied to the child elements,
By better understand how FlexBox works I managed to figure that I was missing a `flex: 1` attribute on the list elements, and therefore the items styling didn't calculated correctly.